# If $f,g$ continuous and $\exists c$ such that $f(c) > g(c)$ then $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $\forall x$, $|x - c| < \delta \implies f(x) > g(x)$.

Tags: analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

So I was reading this particular answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3113739 and I could not for the life of me prove the statement that was given (as symbolised in the title).

What I tried was that given $f$ and $g$ are continuous, I can choose any $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2 > 0$ and corresponding $\delta_1,\delta_2$ such that for all $x$ satisfying $|x - c| < \min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$ we have
\begin{align*}
f(c) - \epsilon_1 < f(x) < f(c) + \epsilon_1\\
g(c) - \epsilon_2 < g(x) < g(c) + \epsilon_2
\end{align*}
I know that $f(x) > g(x) \iff f(x) - g(x) > 0$, so from here I have
\begin{align*}
f(x) - g(x) &> (f(c) - \epsilon_1) - (g(c) + \epsilon_2)\\
&= (f(c) - g(c)) - \epsilon_1 - \epsilon_2
\end{align*}
Now from here the biggest issue I have is that I don't know what I could possibly set $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ such that the last line above is clearly greater than 0.

Could I please have some help?

Comment: You have actually solved your problem. It suffices to get $f(c)-g(c)\ge \epsilon_1+\epsilon_2.$  The simplest choice is $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_2={1\over 2}[f(c)-g(c)].$ But you can as well take $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_2={1\over 4}[f(c)-g(c)].$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc No bloody way, and I had to miss that. Seems like doing proofs at 2am in the morning is a bad idea.

Comment: I find your reasoning the most natural, although you overlooked the conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd suggest simplifying your life: by considering $d(x)=f(x)-g(x)$, it is enough to prove the simplified statement that if $d$ is continuous and $d(c)>0$, then there is a neighborhood of $c$ on which $d(x)>0$ as well.

Second, describe the idea of the solution to yourself before the symbols.  We know that $d$ is continuous, and so it only changes a little in small neighborhoods.  We know that $d(c)>0$. So, we want to pick a neighborhood on which $d(x)$ stays close enough to $d(c)$ that it can't cross below $0$. If $d(x)$ can only differ from $d(c)$ by $\frac{d(c)}{2}$, this will be the case.

To that end, let $\epsilon=\frac{d(c)}{2}$, and note that continuity implies that there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\lvert x-c\rvert<\delta$ implies $\lvert d(x)-d(c)\rvert<\epsilon$.

But that means that
$$
-\frac{d(c)}{2}< d(x)-d(c) < \frac{d(c)}{2},
$$
and adding $d(c)$ implies
$$
\frac{d(c)}{2}<d(x)<\frac{3d(c)}{2}.
$$
But you know that $\frac{d(c)}{2}>0$, so the left inequality proves the result.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to simplify my life. Now that you're showing it to me much clearer I can see how I could have used what I saw earlier here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2258585/suppose-f-x-rightarrow-mathbbr-is-continuous-at-c-and-fc0-prove-tha to help me. Your use of $d$ is the same as $f$ in that context. I also figured out that I wasn't restricted to using $\epsilon = 1/2d(c)$ - I could use $\epsilon = kd(c)$ where $k \in (0,1)$ and everything still works.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\varepsilon=\frac{f(c)-g(c)}2$. Then, since $f-g$ is continuous, there is some $\delta>0$ such that$$|x-c|<\delta\implies\left|f(x)-g(x)-\bigl(f(c)-g(c)\bigr)\right|<\frac{f(c)-g(c)}2.$$But then you cannot possibly have $f(x)-g(x)\leqslant0$ when $|x-c|<\delta$, because then$$\left|f(x)-g(x)-\bigl(f(c)-g(c)\bigr)\right|\geqslant f(c)-g(c)>\frac{f(c)-g(c)}2.$$So,$$|x-c|<\delta\implies f(x)>g(x).$$